# Python error. cant convert int object to "str" imlicitly (Totally confused beginner here)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i decided to make a small string of code that converts your age into lion years (Basically multiplicating your age by 5).
The problem i have is i cant get it to take the age as an integer and input, that or i cant make it print the "lionage" integer below.

Code and error sign below:

```
name = input ("please type your name in: ")
age = int(input ("please type your age in: "))
age = int(age)
five = int(str(5))
lionage = int(age*five)

print ("Hello " + name + "! Your age is " + age + " but in lion years it's " + str(lionage) + " years")
```

Error: can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

I may be wrong on what I got wrong in the code.

(By the way, please prioritize giving me an answer of why its going wrong and how I can fix it simplifying the code to make it smaller. (i want to learn that myself, thanks :) )

Comment: just add `str(age)`.

Comment: you need to change  `age` with `str(age)` in this line  `print ("Hello " + name + "! Your age is " + age + " but in lion years it's " + str(lionage) + " years") `

Comment: By now you may have realized that `five = int(str(5))` is a very convoluted way of doing `five = 5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python can print number, string, ... pretty much anything as long as types are not mixed up. In your case, `age` is a number and the rest of the line you want to print is a string. You need to convert your number to a string by adding `str(age)` instead of just `age`.

Answer (score 0):

Around all variables add str().

For example:

```
a = 21
print("Your age is " + str(a))
```

This would output "Hello World" (without speech marks).

Comment: Actually you don't need `str ()` here !

Comment: You do age is defined as an integer and you can't add a string to an integer.

Comment: I'm talking about your answer, `a` is string so you don't need to cast it again.

Comment: Ohk my bad. I'll edit it

Comment: That is right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Age** is a integer and you trying to concat with an **string**. In python, you cannot do that directly.

```
print ("Your age is " + age)) # <- wrong answer
```

you must convert age to string before concating

```
print ("Your age is " + str(age)) # <- Correct answer
```